# How to get categories and corresponding item count with one DQL query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, tree, stofdoctrineextensions

### Introduction

I am using:

- XAMPP with PHP v7.1.6
- Symfony v3.3.4
- Doctrine v2.5.4
- StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle [[1]](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) in order to manage Tree structure.

### Setting up

To setup Tree structure I used documentation on Symfony.com [[2]](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html) followed by documentation on GitHub [[3]](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md). Then I proceeded with tree setup - used tree entity from example [[4]](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#tree-entity-example) and used code in [[5]](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#basic-usage-examples) to create a tree.

I did setup the tree structure (that represents categories) called `Category`. I added several custom fields to the tree: for example `is_active` that represents active categories.

### At the moment

I am using separate queries to get all `Categories` and corresponding `Item` counts, but i would like to get this info in just one, combined, query.

### Question

Is it possible to get all `Categories` and corresponding `Item` counts in one query using DQL? If so then how?

### MY CODE

Getting all Categories example

```
public function getCategoryTreeNodeArrayByRootId($category_tree_root_id)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('ct')
        ->from('AppBundle:Category', 'ct')
        ->where('ct.root = :root')
        ->setParameter('root', $category_tree_root_id)
        ->orderBy('ct.root, ct.lft', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();

    $query->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS, true);
    $build_my_tree = $query->getArrayResult();

    return $build_my_tree;
}
```

Getting element Item count that corresponds to Category example

```
public function getItemCountsByCategory($in_stock = true)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    if ($in_stock === true)
    {
        // atrod preču skaitu pa kategorijām
        $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('(i.category) as category_id, COUNT(i.id) as record_count')
            ->from('AppBundle:Item', 'i')
            ->where('i.in_stock != 0')
            ->groupBy('i.category')
            ->getQuery();
    }
    else if ($in_stock === false)
    {
        // atrod preču skaitu pa kategorijām
        $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('(i.category) as category_id, COUNT(i.id) as record_count')
            ->from('AppBundle:Item', 'i')
            ->where('i.in_stock == 0')
            ->groupBy('i.category')
            ->getQuery();
    }

    $query->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS, true);
    $item_counts = $query->getArrayResult();

    return $item_counts;
}
```

My `Category` entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection as ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * use repository for handy tree functions
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $category_name_lv;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $is_active;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLeft
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $lft;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLevel
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $lvl;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRight
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $rgt;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRoot
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $root;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeParent
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"lft" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * One Category has Many Items.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Item", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $items;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->items = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set categoryNameLv
     *
     * @param string $categoryNameLv
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setCategoryNameLv($categoryNameLv)
    {
        $this->category_name_lv = $categoryNameLv;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get categoryNameLv
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCategoryNameLv()
    {
        return $this->category_name_lv;
    }

    /**
     * Set isFile
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->is_active = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isFile
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->is_active;
    }

    /**
     * Set lft
     *
     * @param integer $lft
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setLft($lft)
    {
        $this->lft = $lft;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lft
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getLft()
    {
        return $this->lft;
    }

    /**
     * Set lvl
     *
     * @param integer $lvl
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setLvl($lvl)
    {
        $this->lvl = $lvl;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lvl
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getLvl()
    {
        return $this->lvl;
    }

    /**
     * Set rgt
     *
     * @param integer $rgt
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setRgt($rgt)
    {
        $this->rgt = $rgt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get rgt
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getRgt()
    {
        return $this->rgt;
    }

    /**
     * Set root
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Category $root
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setRoot(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $root = null)
    {
        $this->root = $root;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get root
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Category
     */
    public function getRoot()
    {
        return $this->root;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Category $parent
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setParent(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $parent = null)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Category
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Add child
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Category $child
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function addChild(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $child)
    {
        $this->children[] = $child;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove child
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Category $child
     */
    public function removeChild(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $child)
    {
        $this->children->removeElement($child);
    }

    /**
     * Get children
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    /**
     * Add item
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Item $item
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function addItem(\AppBundle\Entity\Item $item)
    {
        $this->items[] = $item;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove item
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Item $item
     */
    public function removeItem(\AppBundle\Entity\Item $item)
    {
        $this->items->removeElement($item);
    }

    /**
     * Get items
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->items;
    }

    /**
     * toString
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getCategoryNameLv();
    }
}
```

My `Item` entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ItemRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="item")
 */
class Item
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $unique_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $name_lv;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $name_ru;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
     */
    protected $category_sub;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500)
     */
    protected $category_full;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500)
     */
    protected $link_lv;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500)
     */
    protected $link_ru;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500)
     */
    protected $local_image_small_url;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500)
     */
    protected $local_image_big_url;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500)
     */
    protected $local_image_big2_url;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500)
     */
    protected $local_image_big3_url;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=3000)
     */
    protected $description_lv;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=3000)
     */
    protected $description_ru;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $in_stock;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $is_exclusive;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $is_new;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Day", inversedBy="items")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="day_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $day;

    /**
     * Many Items have One Category.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="items")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set uniqueId
     *
     * @param string $uniqueId
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setUniqueId($uniqueId)
    {
        $this->unique_id = $uniqueId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get uniqueId
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUniqueId()
    {
        return $this->unique_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nameLv
     *
     * @param string $nameLv
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setNameLv($nameLv)
    {
        $this->name_lv = $nameLv;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nameLv
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNameLv()
    {
        return $this->name_lv;
    }

    /**
     * Set nameRu
     *
     * @param string $nameRu
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setNameRu($nameRu)
    {
        $this->name_ru = $nameRu;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nameRu
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNameRu()
    {
        return $this->name_ru;
    }

    /**
     * Set categorySub
     *
     * @param string $categorySub
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setCategorySub($categorySub)
    {
        $this->category_sub = $categorySub;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get categorySub
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCategorySub()
    {
        return $this->category_sub;
    }

    /**
     * Set categoryFull
     *
     * @param string $categoryFull
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setCategoryFull($categoryFull)
    {
        $this->category_full = $categoryFull;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get categoryFull
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCategoryFull()
    {
        return $this->category_full;
    }

    /**
     * Set linkLv
     *
     * @param string $linkLv
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setLinkLv($linkLv)
    {
        $this->link_lv = $linkLv;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get linkLv
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLinkLv()
    {
        return $this->link_lv;
    }

    /**
     * Set linkRu
     *
     * @param string $linkRu
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setLinkRu($linkRu)
    {
        $this->link_ru = $linkRu;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get linkRu
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLinkRu()
    {
        return $this->link_ru;
    }

    /**
     * Set localImageSmallUrl
     *
     * @param string $localImageSmallUrl
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setLocalImageSmallUrl($localImageSmallUrl)
    {
        $this->local_image_small_url = $localImageSmallUrl;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get localImageSmallUrl
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocalImageSmallUrl()
    {
        return $this->local_image_small_url;
    }

    /**
     * Set localImageBigUrl
     *
     * @param string $localImageBigUrl
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setLocalImageBigUrl($localImageBigUrl)
    {
        $this->local_image_big_url = $localImageBigUrl;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get localImageBigUrl
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocalImageBigUrl()
    {
        return $this->local_image_big_url;
    }

    /**
     * Set localImageBig2Url
     *
     * @param string $localImageBig2Url
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setLocalImageBig2Url($localImageBig2Url)
    {
        $this->local_image_big2_url = $localImageBig2Url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get localImageBig2Url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocalImageBig2Url()
    {
        return $this->local_image_big2_url;
    }

    /**
     * Set localImageBig3Url
     *
     * @param string $localImageBig3Url
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setLocalImageBig3Url($localImageBig3Url)
    {
        $this->local_image_big3_url = $localImageBig3Url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get localImageBig3Url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocalImageBig3Url()
    {
        return $this->local_image_big3_url;
    }

    /**
     * Set descriptionLv
     *
     * @param string $descriptionLv
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setDescriptionLv($descriptionLv)
    {
        $this->description_lv = $descriptionLv;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get descriptionLv
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescriptionLv()
    {
        return $this->description_lv;
    }

    /**
     * Set descriptionRu
     *
     * @param string $descriptionRu
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setDescriptionRu($descriptionRu)
    {
        $this->description_ru = $descriptionRu;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get descriptionRu
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescriptionRu()
    {
        return $this->description_ru;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param string $price
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Set inStock
     *
     * @param integer $inStock
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setInStock($inStock)
    {
        $this->in_stock = $inStock;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get inStock
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getInStock()
    {
        return $this->in_stock;
    }

    /**
     * Set isExclusive
     *
     * @param boolean $isExclusive
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setIsExclusive($isExclusive)
    {
        $this->is_exclusive = $isExclusive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isExclusive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsExclusive()
    {
        return $this->is_exclusive;
    }

    /**
     * Set isExclusive
     *
     * @param boolean $isNew
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setIsNew($isNew)
    {
        $this->is_new = $isNew;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isExclusive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsNew()
    {
        return $this->is_new;
    }

    /**
     * Set day
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Day $day
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setDay(\AppBundle\Entity\Day $day = null)
    {
        $this->day = $day;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get day
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Day
     */
    public function getDay()
    {
        return $this->day;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Category $category
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setCategory(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }
}
```

### Conclusion

Please advise.

Thank you for your time and knowledge.